# Wrapping an opencv implementaion of an error level analysis algorithm using cython

Tags: python, cython, wrapper

i have implemented an error level analysis algorithm using c++(opencv version 2.4) and i want to build a python wrapper for it using cython.
I have read some part of the documentation of cython for c++ but it did not help me and moreover i did not find any extra information for implementing the wrapper online.
It would be really great if someone could guide me and help me solve this problem.

This is my code for which i want to build a pyhton wrapper:

```
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector> 

// Control
int scale = 15,
quality = 75;

// Image containers
cv::Mat input_image,
compressed_image;

void processImage(int, void*)
{

// Setting up parameters and JPEG compression
std::vector<int> parameters;
parameters.push_back(CV_IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY);
parameters.push_back(quality);
cv::imwrite("lena.jpeg", input_image, parameters);

// Reading temp image from the disk
compressed_image = cv::imread("lena.jpeg");

if (compressed_image.empty())
{
  std::cout << "> Error loading temp image" << std::endl;
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

cv::Mat output_image = cv::Mat::zeros(input_image.size(), CV_8UC3);

// Compare values through matrices
for (int row = 0; row < input_image.rows; ++row)
{
 const uchar* ptr_input = input_image.ptr<uchar>(row);
 const uchar* ptr_compressed = compressed_image.ptr<uchar>(row);
 uchar* ptr_out = output_image.ptr<uchar>(row);

    for (int column = 0; column < input_image.cols; column++)
    {
        // Calc abs diff for each color channel multiplying by a scale factor
        ptr_out[0] = abs(ptr_input[0] - ptr_compressed[0]) * scale;
        ptr_out[1] = abs(ptr_input[1] - ptr_compressed[1]) * scale;
        ptr_out[2] = abs(ptr_input[2] - ptr_compressed[2]) * scale;

        ptr_input += 3;
        ptr_compressed += 3;
        ptr_out += 3;
    }
}

// Shows processed image
cv::imshow("Error Level Analysis", output_image);
} 

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
// Verifica se o número de parâmetros necessário foi informado
if (argc < 2)
{
 std::cout << "> You need to provide an image as parameter" << std::endl;
 return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

// Read the image
input_image = cv::imread(argv[1]);

// Check image load
if (input_image.empty())
{
  std::cout << "> Error loading input image" << std::endl;
  return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

// Set up window and trackbar
cv::namedWindow("Error Level Analysis", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
cv::imshow("Error Level Analysis", input_image);
cv::createTrackbar("Scale", "Error Level Analysis", &scale, 100,   processImage);
cv::createTrackbar("Quality", "Error Level Analysis", &quality, 100, processImage);

// Press 'q' to quit
while (char(cv::waitKey(0)) != 'q') {};

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

https://github.com/shreyneil/image_test/blob/master/ela.cpp

Contributions are welcome.
Thank you.

Comment: I think you need to think in detail about what you want: according to your github you have one function that ignores both its parameters and returns nothing - this doesn't look like it can meaningfully be wrapped in Cython. You've also got a main program which accepts some file names as command line arguments and calls opencv - which again isn't really a good candidate to wrap in Cython. You've also put the code off-site so it isn't a self-contained question here. Finally there already is an opencv wrapper for Python? Why not use that?

Comment: Sir,  using cython is part of the task provided to me and is a necessity for completing it. I am new to cython , so it would be really great if you could guide me through wrapping the above code using cython, as in, what will be the classes that would be involved in getting wrapped and other relevant things. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't really clear what you hope to accomplish by this, but it's pretty easy to make the functions callable from Cython. Start by making some small changes to `main` - it will need renaming so that it no longer acts as the main function for a program, and since you only use the second command-line argument as a file name you should change it to:

```
void some_function(char* filename) {
    // Read the image
    input_image = cv::imread(filename);
    // everything else the same
}
```

Then create your Cython wrapper `cy_wrap.pyx`. There are two parts to this. First you need to tell Cython about your two C++ functions (`cdef extern from`). Second you'll need to write a small wrapper function that can call these from Python:

```
cdef extern from "ela.hpp":
    # you'll need to create ela.hpp with declarations for your two functions
    void processImage(int, void*)
    void some_function(char* filename)

# and Python wrappers
def processImagePy():
   # since the parameters are ignored in C++ we can pass anything
   processImage(0,NULL)

def some_functionPy(filename):
   # automatic conversion from string to char*
   some_function(filename)
```

Using this module you'll be able to call `processImagePy` and `some_functionPy`.

To compile it to a Python module you'll need to write a setup.py file. I suggest you follow [the template given in the Cython documentation](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/reference/compilation.html#configuring-the-c-build) (which you have read, right?). Your source files will be `cy_wrap.pyx` and `ela.cpp`. You'll probably want to link to the OpenCV library. You'll need to [specify `language="c++"`](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html)

Comment: Thanx a lot , i was able to build [the wrapper](https://github.com/shreyneil/image_test) class for my program using cython but during the time of  testing i get the following error :                                                            ImportError: /home/shreyash/Desktop/New/ela_c.so: undefined symbol: _ZN2cv14createTrackbarERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES7_PiiPFviPvES9_

Comment: That looks like part of OpenCV. You may need to change what's in `libraries`. I've never used OpenCV though so I can't really help

Comment: Sir, Thanx for your help ,but i think i am not able to link the shared object file with python  and that is why i am getting some errors. Can you please provide the steps to do so. It would be really helpful. Thank you.

Comment: The [link](https://github.com/shreyneil/image_test) contains all the files related to this project .

Comment: I think you're linking to opencv_core correctly, but that probably doesn't contain the symbol. What did you have to link it to to get it to build as a C++ program? On linux (and probably OSX) you can use `ldd ela_c.so` to see what libraries your module is linked to and `objdump -T /path/to/libopencv.so` to get a list of symbols in the library. If the symbol isn't in the library then you need to find it somewhere else.

Comment: Had to include a extra library in the setup.py , Thanx a lot.