# OpenCV error while testing C++ wrapper built

Tags: c++, opencv, shared-libraries, cython

I have been able to implement an algorithm in C++ (error level analysis algorithm for JPEG images) and I have also been able to compile a Python wrapper for the code using cython but at the time of testing it I am facing issues.

This is the [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47969835#comment83025106_48022591) to my previously asked question containing the source code and all relevant information regarding the following post.

I have created a wrapper function for my C++ code and built it using cython but at the time time of testing I a getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Test.py", line 1, in <module>
import ela
ImportError: /home/shreyash/Desktop/New/ela.so: undefined symbol:_ZN2cv14createTrackbarERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES7_PiiPFviPvES9_
```

There seems to some problem with the createtrackbar symbol in the shared object file which is somehow undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with configurations of the setup.py file , i just had to expicitly specify all the libraries being used by my opencv implementation.
After compiling with the help of cython it generated a shared object file 
which had all the defined symbols.